# How to link ends of timing belt into loop

Tags: mechanism

When I buy some length of timing belt I don't know how to link ends of timing belt into loop.

So far I've found one way to do that (thanks to http://www.lasersaur.com/):
http://www.flickr.com/photos/stfnix/8697962319/in/set-72157624491114826

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've found something like this http://www.ebmia.pl/pasy-zebatebrkola-zebate-akcesoria-plytki-mocujace-c-196_50_113.html

Comment: And sth like this http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-HT6E2jk8hko/UY6qKTbcMOI/AAAAAAAAAgQ/Z8sr4tnjG_k/s320/IMAG0054.jpg

Comment: Coswin: How about a picture/sketch - If I read this correctly turning the worm doesn't change the length of the loop any.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a loop would be that it can, well, loop around. The belt never stops. You can't link the ends into a seamless loop. Better buy a looped belt of approximate size and add something to adjust your construct to match the loop size. Leading the belt around 2 wheels in a // shape can help you tighten the loop.

But if you don't really need an endless loop, if you have something that is connected to the "loop" at a fixed point, like in your picture, then that is a different question. In both your picture and the one in the comments the belt isn't looped. Instead one end is simply folded over itself so the teeth bite and prevent it from slipping.

An alternative to this I like is to take both ends of the belt and turn them by 90° with the tooth facing inwards. Place a worm gear between those two ends and a hollow cylinder around it so both belt ends are pressed into the worm gear with their teeth. Now you can turn the worm gear to tighten or loosen the belt "loop". You can 3D print the worm gear and enclosing cylinder to match your belt tooth profile and thickness.

Comment: That would only "walk" the worm "up" one belt but "down" the other belt, the end result being zero change in belt length.